# How to plot sine wave graph of audio being recorded at same time?

Tags: android, graph, plot, audio-recording

i want to record audio in my application and i also want to show sinusoidal wave graph on run-time. I have used `AudioRecord` class to record audio on runtime . Now i want to show sinusoidal graph of the waves being recorded. I can get max amplitude using `android APi`. How can i use it to plot **sinwave graph** in my application.